# Inkscape: Transform geometry of cloned path, but not the style

Tags: inkscape, svg, path, stroke, transform

I want to design an illustration with a curved path and a skewed version of it. The original path `org` is somewhat "in flux" and a moving target; I have to adjust the shape of `org` so that important features of the skewed version `skew` are clearly visible, and vice versa.
So, `skew` really should be a linked clone of `org` rather than just a transformed copy.

However, I want the skewing to only affect the *nodes* (geometry) of the path, not the *stroke* (style). This works as soon as I unlink the clone, which gives me full access to all style attributes; but unfortunately this means that it, ahem, is not linked anymore.
(Strangely, this holds for "proper" paths, but apparently not for circles or ellipses; see the image below, 2nd row.)

What I'm after is the looks of the last column, but without unlinking.
([edit] Sorry, imgur decided to shrink it smaller than I expected. All are paths with strokes; first and last row are paths, second row is an ellipse. Note the varying stroke angles and visual thickness of the third column vs. the others.)

[image: Skew on clones]

So, is there any way to decouple style and geometry for cloning? (In a perfect world, I would also be able to change other stylistic attributes, e.g., the color of a clone; although I understand that this could be "difficult" to specify for cloned groups etc...)

N.b.: For *setting* size and position via the top toolbar, Inkscape offers buttons to enable and disable the scaling of stroke and corner radii, as well as pattern movement/rescaling. This doesn't seem to work for the transformations applied via the Transform tool (Ctrl+Shift+M). I understand that this is due to the fact that the transform tool sets a transformation matrix in SVG, while *setting* size and position is done immediately via recomputation of the coordinates of the control points.

The SVGTiny 1.2 spec has a [`vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/painting.html#NonScalingStroke) property that should allow exactly what I want: it makes stroke "resistant" to transformations. Unfortunately, I cannot make it work for `use` elements, despite the fact that AFAICS it should apply to them, too.

Comment: Why not just rotate the clone instead of skewing it?

Comment: Well, in this particular case because the algorithm I want to illustrate with the figure is based on a skewing, not a rotation...

Comment: But that's somewhat moot; my question applies also to other transformations as well (in particular, scaling comes to mind, where lines might almost disappear or blow up against the artist's intention).
And even rotation might change the stroke, at least in corner cases: just tried with an "empty" path with an end marker, which will be rotated for the clone and in the original angle for the unlinked copy. That might be a corner case, but I use (exploit?) such constructs sometimes to have convenient "point" markers without any proper extent, rather than circles, crosses etc.

Comment: And that's for exactly the reason why I posed the question: If I mark special points of the original picture with, e.g., circles, I have to un-transform them again in the skewed version; with "empty paths", it suffices to unlink, and I get the same appearance on both original and skew.

Comment: Awesome, your question is my answer: I come looking for this "For setting size and position via the top toolbar, Inkscape offers buttons to enable and disable the scaling of stroke and corner radii" and you have answered it in a quick "N.b."